# Find all the critical numbers of $\sqrt[3]{x+1}+10 $ on $\ ( − 2 , 4)$

Tags: calculus

A question for some math assignment I have. We have done this with normal functions, but we haven't done any when given a point. So far all I have done with these questions is finding the derivative and then making it = 0 and finding the critical points that way, but I'm not sure if it is different because we are now given a point. I have figured out that the derivative is:

$\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}}$

Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: $(-2,4)$ isn't a point, it's the open interval $-2<x<4$. So you're finding all critical numbers that fall between $2$ and $4$ exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion is stemming from thinking that $(-2,4)$ is referring to a point. It is actually stating an interval i.e.

> Find all the critical numbers of $\sqrt[3]{x+1}+10$ on $(-2,4) $

is the same as:

> Find all the critical numbers of $\sqrt[3]{x+1}+10$  for $ -2 < x < 4$.

See [interval notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) for more details.

As for the answer to your question, if you define critical points to be the locations where the derivative is $0$, this function has no critical points in this interval.

You have $f(x)  = \sqrt[3]{x+1}+10$ and so:

$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{3(x+1)^{2 \over 3}}
$$

which is never equal to $0$. Thus $f(x)$ has no critical points.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+1}+10$$
$x \in (-2;4)$
$$f'(x)=\left((x+1)^{\frac13}\right)'=\frac13(x+1)^{-\frac23}=\frac13\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}}$$

Comment: $f'(-1)$ is not $0$: it's simply not defined.

Comment: @Bernard: I thought that the critical point - is when the derivative is zero or does not exist.

Comment: @Roman83 I've definitely seen such points both included and excluded in different literature.

Comment: As far as I know, it's only when the derivative is $0$.  Else an everywhere non-differentiable function would have all points critical.

Comment: @Bernard "Some authors include in the critical points the limit points where the function may be prolongated by continuity and where the derivative is not define" from the wiki page for critical points.